# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException map has no value for "orderId" in Spring Restful service

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm working on a Payment related Restful service. when I try to call the API it occurs an exception called `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` map has no value for `orderId`

As a background, I created HttpHeaders and LinkedMultiValueMap and put values to it and called the API.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> uriVars = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
uriVars.add("merchantId", _paymentInstrument.getAcquirerMid());
uriVars.add("orderId", _paymentInstrument.getOrderId().toString());
uriVars.add("transactionId", _paymentInstrument.getTransactionId().toString());

VoidRequest voidRequest = createVoidRequest(_paymentInstrument.getTargetTransactionId());
HttpEntity<VoidRequest> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(voidRequest, headers);
TransactionResponse voidResponse = null;
try {
    ResponseEntity<TransactionResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(getEnvironment().getProperty(IPG_TRANSACTION_URL), 
        HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, TransactionResponse.class, uriVars);
        voidResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
        log.info(LogSupport.PG_LOGS_CARGILLS_VOID_TRX + "[AcquirerMID ={};TransactionId ={};ResponseCode={};ResponseText={}]", _paymentInstrument.getAcquirerMid(), 
                _paymentInstrument.getTransactionId(), voidResponse.getResponse().getAcquirerCode(), voidResponse.getResponse().getAcquirerMessage());
} catch (ResourceAccessException rae) {
    throw rae;
} catch (Exception e) {     
    voidResponse = new TransactionResponse();
    voidResponse.setResult("ERROR");
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
    error.setCause("EXCEPTION");
    error.setExplanation(e.getMessage());
}
```

This occurs an exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException map has no value for "orderId".

Comment: Can you check the value of `_paymentInstrument.getOrderId()`?

Comment: Wait i debug and show the result.

Comment: Yes it has a value and result "1161".

Comment: Can you put the error and the stacktrace in the question?

Comment: @Rashin Exception is java.lang.illegalargumentexception map has no value for "orderId" . detailMessage of the exception also Map has no value for 'orderId'.

Comment: Yes I saw in the question but the whole stacktrace would help. :)

Comment: @Das_J, what is the value of getEnvironment().getProperty(IPG_TRANSACTION_URL)

Comment: @TechFree. I found what i went wrong it is i missed the parameter name orderid as orderId. Thanks for the direction .

Answer (score 0):

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).queryParam("criterion", criterion);
Product product = restTemplate.getForObject(builder.build().toUri(), Product.class);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. in my case, if I assign a key value pair to a variable like this :

don't do that

```
uriVariables.put("from", fromValue);
```

do that

```
uriVariables.put("fromValue", fromValue);
```

In a HashMap type, the key must always be the same as the dynamic variables in the url I'm going to use.

Code example here

```
@GetMapping("/currency-conversion/from/{fromValue}/to/{toValue}/quantity/{quantity}")
  public CurrencyConversion calculateCurrencyConversion(@PathVariable String fromValue,
      @PathVariable String toValue, @PathVariable BigDecimal quantity) {

    HashMap<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
    uriVariables.put("fromValue", fromValue);
    uriVariables.put("toValue", toValue);
    ResponseEntity<CurrencyConversion> responseEntity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(
        "http://localhost:8000/currency-exchange/from/{fromValue}/to/{toValue}",
        CurrencyConversion.class, uriVariables);

    CurrencyConversion currencyConversion = responseEntity.getBody();

    return new CurrencyConversion(currencyConversion.getId(), fromValue, toValue,
        currencyConversion.getConversionMultiple(), quantity,
        quantity.multiply(currencyConversion.getConversionMultiple()),
        currencyConversion.getEnvironment());
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Check typo mistakes for `orderId`
2. If you declare dynamic values in property file, compare name with property Ex: `{orderId}`